# Slides Apps Script: PageElementRange not returning in same order as user's selection

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm working with Apps Script in Slides. The user can select multiple objects on the slide using Shift+Click, and I'm retrieving the selection with `SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSelection().getPageElementRange()`.

However, I'm noticing that the order in which the user selects the shapes IS always correct when 2 objects are selected, but is often wrong when 3 or more objects are selected - the ordering with 3+ objects seems to be random and doesn't follow a pattern I can detect.

Any pointers here on how to get the order of the user's selection?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem - were you able to solve the issue?

Comment: No. In cases with 3+ objects, it seems like most of the time the array will have the first selected object as the first element of the array. But I wasn't able to figure out a way to reliably get the order of all selections.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the pattern is their z-index order (stacking / layering order).
Would be useful to know their selection order, as well as their z-index order.